# sorting stack in ascending order using recursion

Tags: sorting, recursion, stack

I am interested to know how i can sort a stack in **ascending** order using **recursion**
I already sort an stack in descending order using recursion but can't find a logic for ascending order.
Please tell me some logic for it .
Thanks in advance
**edit:**

*my code of sort function and insert function for sort the stack in descending order*

```
void sort(stack<int>&st)
{
    if(st.size()==1)
        return;
    int ele=st.top();
    st.pop();
    sort(st);
    insert(st,ele);
    return;
}


void insert(stack<int>&st,int ele)
{
    int x=st.size(),y=st.top();
    if(x==0||y<=ele)
    {
        st.push(ele);
        return;
    }
    int t=st.top();
    st.pop();
    insert(st,ele);
    st.push(t);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What's your solution for descending?

Comment: @Manuel please see my sort function and insert function from the link given below. 

I am new at stackoverflow . 

as a result i am failing to give my code at comment section . 
please check it from this link : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6rZghhVpnv/

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't be in a comment, should be in the question. Anyway, can't you just change `<=` to `>=`?

Comment: @manuel it's terminating without showing any thing in output if i change <= to >= .

Comment: Then probably your code for descending isn't correct, either.

Answer (score 0):

First write `insert` that takes a **sorted** stack, `s`, and a value to be inserted, `v`. This function will ensure `v` will be inserted in order and maintains the ascending sort of `s` -

```js
function insert(s, v)
{ if (s.length == 0) return push(s, v)
  const r = []
  while (s.length)
    if (peek(s) < v) break
    else move1(s, r)
  push(s, v)
  move(r, s)
}
```

If we start with an empty stack, `s = []`, we can `insert` values one at a time to get a stack sorted in ascending order -

```js
const s = []
insert(s, 7)
insert(s, 2)
insert(s, 9)
insert(s, 4)
console.log(s)
```

```js
[2,4,7,9]
```

Our `insert` function depends on other convenient stack operations we need to write. Such as `move1` that moves *one* item from `q` to `p` -

```js
function move1(q, p)
{ push(p, pop(q)) }
```

And `move` that moves *all* of `q` to `p` -

```js
function move(q, p)
{ while (q.length) move1(q, p) }
```

Now if we start with an unsorted stack, `s`, to sort `descending`, we create a new stack, `r`, and `insert` each `pop`ped value from `s`. The temporary `r` will be in ascending order, but the goal is to sort `s`! Simply `move` all `r` to `s` and now `s` is in descending order -

```js
function descending(s)
{ const r = []
  while(s.length)
    insert(r, pop(s))
  move(r, s)
}

const q = [7,1,6,5,4,9,3]
descending(q)
console.log(q)
```

```js
[1,3,4,5,6,7,9]
```

To sort `ascending`, we first sort by `descending` then simply `reverse` -

```js
function ascending(s)
{ descending(s)
  reverse(s)
}

function reverse(s)
{ const q = [], p = []
  move(s, q)
  move(q, p)
  move(p, s)
}

const q = [7,1,6,5,4,9,3]
ascending(q)
console.log(JSON.stringify(q))
```

```js
[9,7,6,5,4,3,1]
```

Finally implement these other basic stack operations, `pop`, `push`, and `peek` -

```js
function pop(s)
{ return s.pop() }

function push(s, v)
{ s.push(v) }

function peek(s)
{ const v = pop(s)
  push(s, v)
  return v
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro for describing  this  nice approach